Where am I going wrong when obtaining the Hamiltonian density for the electromagnetic field?
I'm trying to verify that the Hamiltonian density for the classical electromagnetic field is equal to the energy density. But the electric field is disappearing and only the energy density of the magnetic field remains, and i can't see where i'm going wrong.In Gaussian units, i'm doing the following:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal L=-\frac{1}{16\pi}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=-\frac{1}{16\pi}2[B^2-E^2].\tag{1}
\end{equation}
So:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal \pi^{\mu}=\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_tA_{\mu})}=\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_0A_{\mu})}=-\frac{1}{16\pi c}\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_0A_{\mu})}(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}).\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Here I am using the fact that: $\partial^{\mu}(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu})=2(\partial^{\mu}F_{\mu\nu})F^{\mu\nu}$, so:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal \pi^{\mu}=-\frac{1}{8\pi c}\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_0A_{\mu})}(F_{\mu\nu})\bigg]F^{\mu\nu}=-\frac{1}{8\pi c}\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_0A_{\mu})}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu})\bigg]F^{\mu\nu}=-\frac{1}{8\pi c}\bigg(\delta_{\mu}^0\delta_{\mu}^{\nu}-\delta_{\nu}^0\delta_{\mu}^{\mu}\bigg)F^{\mu\nu}=-\frac{1}{8\pi c}(F^{0\mu}-F^{\mu0})=-\frac{1}{4\pi c}F^{0\mu}.\tag{3}
\end{equation}
And, since $F^{00}=0$ , $ $$\pi^{0}=0.$
Then i try to get the Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal H =\mathcal \pi^{\mu}\dot{A}_{\mu}-\mathcal L=\mathcal \pi^i\dot{A}_i+\frac{1}{16\pi}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=-\frac{1}{4\pi c}F^{0i}c\partial_0A_i+\frac{1}{16\pi}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=-\frac{1}{4\pi }F^{0i}\partial_0A_i+\frac{1}{16\pi}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}.\tag{4}
\end{equation}
At this point i'm separating $\partial_0A_i$ into symmetrical and antisymmetrical parts:
\begin{equation}
\partial_0A_i=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[(\partial_0A_i-\partial_iA_0)+(\partial_0A_i+\partial_iA_0)\bigg]=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[F_{0i}+\mathcal O_{0i}\bigg]\tag{5}
\end{equation}
Where $\mathcal O_{0i}$ is a symmetrical. Thus:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal H=-\frac{1}{4\pi }F^{0i}\frac{1}{2}\bigg[F_{0i}+\mathcal O_{0i}\bigg]+\frac{1}{16\pi}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=-\frac{1}{8\pi }F^{0i}F_{0i}+\frac{1}{8\pi}[B^2-E^2]=-\frac{1}{8\pi }(-E^i)E_i+\frac{1}{8\pi}[B^2-E^2]=\frac{1}{8\pi}E^2+\frac{1}{8\pi}B^2-\frac{1}{8\pi}E^2=\frac{1}{8\pi}B^2.\tag{6}
\end{equation}
I seem to be forgetting some "2" factor. I've re-done it a few times and i'm still getting it wrong :(

The step where you divide $\partial_0 A_i$ into a "symmetrical" and "antisymmetrical" part, and drop the term involving the symmetric part, doesn't make sense, because the indices are different from each other. Explicitly expand out the term you dropped, and you'll find it's not zero.

What you're supposed to do is keep $\partial_0 A_i$ as it is, then contract it against $F_{0i}$. You'll get something which isn't gauge invariant, which is actually what's expected to happen -- to get a gauge invariant stress-energy tensor you need to add Belinfante corrections, which you can read about in most field theory texts.

Thank you, i think I was doing it in "automatic mode", I didn't notice that $\partial_0A_i$ $is not a tensor.

Hints:

Instead of OP's eq. (5) the prescription of the Legendre transformation is to eliminate the velocity variable
$$ \dot{A}_i~\equiv~\partial_0A_i~=~F_{0i} +\partial_i A_0 \tag{5'}$$
by introducing the momentum variable $F_{0i}$.

The last term $\partial_i A_0$ in eq. (5') contributes to a term in the Hamiltonian density ${\cal H}$ of the form: A Lagrange multiplier $A_0$ times a Gauss constraint $\partial_iF^{0i}$ (up to a total derivative term). This  implements Gauss law in the Hamiltonian formulation.



Thanks for the help. I really didn't realize that $\partial_0A_i$ is not a tensor.
